# Video Modal Box Opens But Greyed Out

Tags: javascript, html, video, modal-dialog

I'm Trying To Make Lectures Page That Contains Every Lecture Name With A button And When You Press The Button, It Opens A Modal Box Of Your Desired Video. But It Keeps Doing Like This
Tried To remove `videoSRCauto` and couple of other things and nothing happend.
The Expected Action : To Click On One Of These Buttons The Modal Opened And The Video Appears

```js
$(function() {
  $(".video").click(function () {
    var theModal = $(this).data("target"),
        videoSRC = $(this).attr("data-video"),
        videoSRCauto = videoSRC + "";
    $(theModal + ' source').attr('src', videoSRCauto);
    $(theModal + ' button.close').click(function () {
      $(theModal + ' source').attr('src', videoSRC);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata|Source+Sans+Pro:200,300,400,600');

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #E0E0E0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #151E3F;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  > * {
    margin: 5px;
  }
}

.media {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
  img {
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }

.layer {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 10px;
  height: 90%;
  background: #FFF;
  color: #151E3F;
  transition: all 0.9s ease;
}
  p {
    transition: all 0.9s ease;
    transform: scale(0.1)
  }

p {
  font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing:1px;
}

.media:hover .layer {
  opacity: 0.8;
  width: 90%;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
  p {
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: all 0.9s ease;
  }
@media (max-width: 800px){
  body {
    transform: scale(0.6);
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .wrapper {
    display: block;
    > * {
      margin: 10px;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>..</title>
</head>
<body>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.0.0/magnific-popup.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="icon" href="http://laurefinch.beget.tech/fav.ico">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.0.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<h1>Lectures</h1>
<body oncontextmenu="return false;">
<div class="media">
<div class="layer">
                <button class="btn btn-lg video" data-video="https://clienti.dk/media/1140/friheden-video.mp4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal">Marwan Moussa</button>

  <div class="modal fade" id="videoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <video controls  controlsList="nodownload" width="100%">
            <source src="https://clienti.dk/media/1140/friheden-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          </video>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
      <p style="position: absolute;top:130px;font-size:12px">Sheraton</p>
                <div id="headerPopup" class="mfp-hide embed-responsive embed-responsive-21by9">
      </div>
  </div>
<img src="Lectures/1st/upload/Marwan Moussa - Sheraton.jpg" alt="" />
</div><div class="media">
<div class="layer">
                <button class="btn btn-lg video" data-video="https://clienti.dk/media/1140/friheden-video.mp4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal">Final Maro Trying</button>

  <div class="modal fade" id="videoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <video controls  controlsList="nodownload" width="100%">
            <source src="https://clienti.dk/media/1140/friheden-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          </video>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
      <p style="position: absolute;top:130px;font-size:12px">Sheraaaton</p>
                <div id="headerPopup" class="mfp-hide embed-responsive embed-responsive-21by9">
      </div>
  </div>
<img src="Lectures/1st/upload/Finaal.jpg" alt="" />
</div><div class="media">
<div class="layer">
                <button class="btn btn-lg video" data-video="https://clienti.dk/media/1140/friheden-video.mp4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal">Marwaaaaan</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Matrix, there does not appear to be a clear question to the community here.  Can you please edit your question so that others understand what specifically you're looking for help with?

Comment: i have some buttons in the page that supposed to when i click on it a modal box with video open